# Where to ask a question when you don't know where to ask your question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

When I have a question about programming, like how to approach a programming problem, that I can't find a clear answer to on Google, or in a forum, or in the help centre, is there somewhere I can go to ask, "Where can I ask my question?"

Comment: Where did you go to figure out where to ask where you can ask how to figure out where you should ask your question?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: [Where do I ask where to ask?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168103/where-do-i-ask-where-to-ask) Though if it's about programming, Meta Stack Overflow (where you are now) is an equally safe bet.

Comment: That's so...meta.

Comment: What about http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Or in chat, I sometimes take my questions to chat so they can point my in a more clear direction first.

Comment: @DasBeasto No, programmers is not the appropriate place to go to find out where you should ask a particular type of question.

Comment: @Servy speaking as a denizen of [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/21/the-whiteboard)... chat isn't a bad place and we do try to provide guidance as to where something should be asked (or even if its a good question for the SE framework) and won't chase people away who come in good faith and learn from previous answers.

Comment: @Servy I meant that more as the place where he could actually ask the question not to ask where to ask. His question "how to approach a programming problem", seems to fit in fairly well with "conceptual questions about software development" (that boards description)

Comment: As an aside, reading [Where to start?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6366/40980) can cut down on the number of false starts when asking such a question.  Make sure to have a clear problem when asking to avoid having a too broad one.

Comment: You ask on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168103/179419).

Comment: @DasBeasto: Programmers is extremely strict in their definition of what is on-topic there. Without knowing the exact topic of the question to be asked, I'd be *very* careful about referring people there; if you send someone with an inappropriate question for that site, they will receive a very unwelcome reception.

Answer (score 6):

You can ask on this very site, the Meta of Stack Overflow, where you can ask a specific question if you can't figure out or have doubt where it would fit best.

Keep in mind that your question still need to be programming related to be answered here. If you're about to ask for completely unrelated stuff you can ask on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) but the process is the same.

Before you post here:

- research the [`/help` page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) of [potential sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites), specially for what is on- and off-topic
- research of each potential site the meta site for similar requests
- summarize your reasoning why you think your question can or can't fit on a site
- make a complete, ready to post draft of the question you want to ask

  - use the citation markup `> text`  to clearly distinguish the draft
- ask for either an improvement of the draft question so it becomes on-topic  and/or a site recommendation
- tag your question [support](/questions/tagged/support) and [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation)

If you're even unsure if a meta post will be well received, you could try a chat room first but be prepared to answer the above mentioned bullets as well.