# Why are some pages randomly less secure than others?

Tags: support, ssl

I was just browsing Meta when I noticed the following (I was on [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266699/2246344) post in a different tab when I took the right screenshot),

[image]
[image]

Now this is where the "randomness" comes in. I only get the left screenshot for certain posts (*roughly* 1 in every ~300), and when I do, if I close the tab and reopen the post in a new one, I get the right shot (as usual). But this doesn't always work, sometimes I have to close, wait ~5 minutes, and then reopen a new tab.

I've also noticed this behaviour on SO (only once from what I've seen), so far - if I recall correctly - I've seen this happen four times on Meta. I also disabled all add-ons/extensions and still got the same results.

In addition, I've also found that once I come across an "insecure" page and then continue to view other posts (on the same domain in the same tab), it still says the page isn't secure (perhaps this is a bug with Chrome?).

Here's a shot of the console for the in/secure pages,

[image]
[image]

Even more puzzling, I've managed to view the same post in different tabs, one says it's secure, the other not,

[image]
[image]

For the left shot tab I was previously at Meta's home page (and again, it said the page was insecure), I then opened a post in that same tab and took the shot. For the right one, I just opened a new tab of the same post.

What's causing this to randomly occur?

---

<sup>Browser: Chrome 36.0.1985.125,

OS: Windows 7 Home Premium (32-bit).</sup>

Comment: Check your console when the red icon comes up. Is there a script (or even stylesheet) included in the list of insecure content, as opposed to the usual images?

Comment: @minitech Give me a moment, I'll check...

Comment: @minitech [Here's](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OrA1i.png) what I usually get. And [here's](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KrqHg.png) what I get for the insecure page.

Comment: Is there anything important at the bottom of the console in that second screenshot? If not, it may just be the number of images, or the fact that they come from a script instead of the page…

Comment: @minitech Nope, just the same warnings. But how does that explain the "randomness" though, since this doesn't happen with every post?

Comment: Is it not just that images in posts default to http srcs? (full disclosure I know nothing about https)

Comment: @OGHaza Not sure, but I still don't understand how that would explain why this only occurs with the odd post.

Comment: @Sam, I meant to say, does it not only occur when viewing posts with embedded images whilst viewing the site through https? - ah wait, in both instances (secure vs insecure) your console shows the error? in that case I have no idea and can be ignored

Comment: @OGHaza Yep, same errors for pages with and without images.

Comment: @OGHaza And again, I've just gone to the [home tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/home) and it says it's insecure, the weird thing here is even if I view any post in the same tab, it still says the page - whatever it is - is insecure, but if I open a new tab it's fine.

Comment: Just stating the obvious here, but the first error message complains about the "behaviour of the page" while the second one only complains about the "look of the page". My guess is that a script file gets loaded over http, and only throws the behaviour error when it is not loaded from cache... maybe?

Comment: @OGHaza They are loaded over whatever the protocol of the original page is if they are defined as "//site.ip/name.png" or "name.png", or otherwise loaded over the protocol specified (e.g. "`http://site.ip/name.png`").

Comment: See if your console records any "page was loaded over HTTPS, but **ran** insecure content" warnings (as opposed to "*displayed* insecure content"). As has been said, the difference lies between "look of the page" and "behaviour of the page", referring to resources loaded over plain HTTP. Based on a quick look at the Chromium source, the "look" is for images, and "behaviour" is almost everything else - css, scripts, svg, fonts, ...  The console messages are different for the two cases - "*displayed* insecure content" refers to the former, and "*ran* insecure content" to the latter.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Ok, I've just cleared my cache and randomly browsed ~50 posts from Meta and SO, so far I can't seem to get the behaviour warning up, yet (remember I said It only comes up every ~300 posts, so it may be a while)...

Comment: I imagine it might have something to do with loading an advert that doesn't use HTTPS.

Comment: @TomHart I've got an adblock extension enabled. But even with all extensions disabled the same thing still happens.

Comment: You know that HTTPS is not fully supported yet don't you?

Comment: @TomHart There are no ads on Meta. Also, if you look at the URLs in the screenshots, you can see that the first one is the OP's avatar.

Comment: What? You're using a 32 bit OS?! :O

Comment: @bjb568 I know, it's rather tragic actually. My machine supports 64-bit but Stone (the manufacture) decided it would be fun to install the 32-bit version instead. Thankfully, I've got Ubuntu 64-bit laying around somewhere...

Comment: Looks to me like imgur links aren't adjusted to https:// when the user is on https. This is something that could be fixed, though I doubt that's what's causing the certificate errors.

Answer (score 15):

The left warning says that the page "can be modified by an attacker to change the behavior of the page" whereas the right page says "can be modified by an attacker to change the look of the page."

That suggests that the left page has a non-SSL script, whereas the right page has a non-SSL resource of some other type (perhaps an image).

Probably there is an advertisement that is non-SSL. Sometimes this includes JavaScript, hence the random variation.

In all cases this is sub-optimal. Having non-SSL resources on an SSL page can (I believe, I'm not an expert) lead to all sorts of confusion and social-engineering style attacks.

It's like a buffer overrun. Sometimes it crashes your application. Sometimes you get unlucky and you are able to continue executing.