# Machine learning project feasibility question

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a stack exchange for asking whether or not machine learning would be a valid solution for a specific project. I want to give details of issues that I am running into, and see if any experts in the field could tell me whether or not machine learning would be beneficial for may case.

**Synopsis as asked for below:**

I have a web app where users upload PDF documents, which contain several different sections. The sections consists of somewhat standardized numbers and are typically found in a table of contents within the PDF. I need to be able to determine which section I am in when reading through the PDF in Python. This has proven to be very difficult with inconsistent results, because the forms themselves are not standardized, and seem to have minor differences between all of them. I have currently been using a "rules" based approach and since the forms are not the same, I have basically been cherry picking all of the oddities that throw it off. This approach is never going to give us the accuracy that we desire. It seems like if I am able to provide enough sample data then machine learning might be able to be utilized, but I am really not familiar enough with it to know.

Comment: Can you give a sample synopsis of your question?  There's a *chance* it's on-topic somewhere in the network (but not here since this is more conceptual than implementation).

Comment: You might find this helpful https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320733/578411 to gather the stuff currently missing from your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> - Given Facebook Likes, is there an ML technique to predict age and gender?
> - ...